# How to search associations, only IF they exist (so not using a join)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have an Order, that has a title. Order has an optional Company that has a name. Order also has multiple LineItems, that connect to Products, that have a name.

I want to create a search feature that allows a user to query Order.title, Company.name and/or Products.name. If an Order has no connected Company or Products, that should not stop it from matching.

For example, this doesn't work, because if there's no Company, even if the Order.name matches, it won't return because the join wont work.

```
Order.joins([:company, {line_items: [:product]}]).
      where("orders.name = ? OR company.name = ? OR product.name = ?", query)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use only `joins`, Rails does a inner join. You can use `left_joins`, so that the query will return rows even where the association doesn't exist:

```
Order.left_joins([:company, {line_items: [:product]}]).
      where("orders.name = ? OR company.name = ? OR product.name = ?", query)
```

As max suggested, if you're gonna use some value from those nested associations (like the company name or something like that) I would recommend you to use `eager_load` instead of `left_joins`, so rails will load the data from those tables and it will avoid additional queries

I would also recommend, since you're doing a search, to uppercase both your columns and you query, so it won't be case sensitive. Also, would be good to use LIKE instead of EQUAL comparator (so it will return the record even if it doesn't match entirely). Something like this should work better:

```
Order.left_joins([:company, {line_items: [:product]}]).
      where("UPPER(orders.name) LIKE ? OR UPPER(company.name) LIKE ? OR UPPER(product.name) LIKE ?", query.upcase)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you are intending to use the joined tables for example in the view use `.eager_load` instead of `.left_joins` to avoid n+1 query issues.

Comment: Not necessarily - if you know that you will be using the data `.eager_load` performs a single query with an outer join. `.includes` tries to be smart and performs two queries or delegates to `.eager_load` if the where clause references the joined tables. http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2017/01/24/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where

Comment: @max I usually use includes exactly 'cause it decides which approach is better. In that case I'll trust you and update the answer